# navigating between state will reload JS and CSS every time or only once

Tags: angularjs

I have one ng-app, one app.js which contain all .state (around 30states). 
I am including around 7 JS files in home.html

I am using (ui-view) ui.router.

My folder structure is as following.

```
home.html
js\
    angular.js
    angular-filter.js
    ...
css\
app\
    app.js
    school\
            html\
                school.html
                schoolSetup.html
            js\
                school.js       -> contain school related controller
    someMore\
            html\
                more.html
                more.html
            js\
                more.js     -> contain more related controller
```

state looks like ....

```
            .state('schoolProperties', {
                url: '/list/:academicYear',
                templateUrl: 'app/school/html/school.html',
                controller: 'schoolCtrl as vm'
            })
            .state('schoolSetup', {
                url: '/schoolSetup/:schoolId',
                templateUrl: 'app/school/html/schoolSetup.html',
                controller: 'schoolSetupCtrl as vm'
            })
```

when I am hitting url home.html, it is loading 7 JS files which I included and it taking around 2 seconds.

**My question is, while navigating from one state to another, Is those 7 JS reload (download)   every time? or it load (download) only once.**

I am watching chrome inspect network .. showing finish time in incremental mode for example state-1 1sec, state2=2sec, state1 again = 3sec.

Answer (score 0):

They are loaded only once as the home.html is the container of the views and the inner content only is loaded (inside the templates you provided).

If you see it loading with Status 200 .. check if the disable cache is checked in the network console. This causes them to reload constantly not from cache (I was caught in this with images loading constantly in a carousel)